# What's the best way to compare variable string equality in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string-comparison

I'm trying to check a string passed through the URL and get back all results from a MySQL database where that string is a match.

I send different queries based on the input, but the one in question looks basically like this (it's really much longer):

```
if ($projectsname) {$result = mysql_query("SELECT item FROM items WHERE projectname=$projectsname",$db)}
```

The issue is that $projectsname is a string. All my other queries return an integer and work fine.  But in this case I can't get it to give me a proper result in the actual PHP code unless I put it in quotes, and here's how I did that:

```
$projectsname = (isset($_GET['projectname']) && !empty($_GET['projectname'])) ? '"'. $_GET['projectname'] .'"' : 0;
```

...by appending the quotes to the data that creates the variable. And that works. It just seems wrong to me.

Is there a better way of making this comparison?

(I wish I could say this was a newbie question, but it's something I've often had trouble with in my years as a designer who tries to code.)

Feel free to edit the question if you know better terminology than I have used here (and let me know what your edits were--I'm having a hard time phrasing the question.).

Comment: You can put quotes around a numeric value in MySQL and it will still work.  You're making this too hard.

Comment: Just in case, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: AJ: it's not a numerical value. It's a text string.

Comment: Macmade: care to demonstrate?

Comment: @David: Suppose `$projectsname='\'; DROP TABLE items; --'`

Comment: Also read up about `mysql_real_escape_string` and SQL injections.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for giving an example. I couldn't make it work, but I'm guessing you've simplified it a bit from how someone wanting to delete my table would actually use it. Sanmai, thanks for pointing to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($projectsname) {$result = mysql_query("SELECT item FROM items WHERE projectname='$projectsname'",$db)}
```

You need to quote strings that you pass to mysql.

Comment: Well, I'm confused. Wouldn't quoting the variable name pass the variable name instead of passing the variable values?

Comment: Now, that's why you have single quotes inside. When you use double qoutes in php5 ("), you can put variable names in it, and php will replace that as variable values.

Comment: "SELECT item FROM items WHERE projectname='$projectsname'" is the same as "SELECT item FROM items WHERE projectname='".$projectsname."'"

Comment: Really? Was this once the accepted way of doing things, and now it's part of the language? It just seems wrong to me to ever pass a variable in quotes.

Comment: Quoting strings is part of the SQL syntax. Writing variable names inside double quotes is new in php5. You need to quote strings in SQL sentences so that the SQL server distincts data from commands.

Comment: @Anze Writing variable names inside double quotes is as old as PHP itself.

Comment: @Anze you're probably thinking of...it's either heredoc or nowdoc, I get the two confused.  But it's not double-quoted strings.  That goes wayyyyyy back.

Comment: Sure enough, single-quoting the variable name works. I'm now confused how you would pass a literal value, if you wanted to do that--I guess the same way, and PHP just knows to look for the dollar sign and interpret it as a variable. It seems so fundamentally wrong, you would think tutorials might make mention of it some time.
Whether this is a new thing in PHP or not, I didn't know about it, and Anze, I appreciate your taking the time to answer, and to everyone for their comments.

Comment: No problem, just remember that if you want to include the quotes in the string you are passing to mysql you need to esacpe them.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
echo "SELECT item FROM items WHERE projectname=$projectsname";
```

to see what query you're actually sending.

Also read up about `mysql_real_escape_string` and about SQL injections in general. Consider the following example of a very typical SQL injection your code is prone to:

```
$projectsname = "123 OR 1=1";
echo "DELETE FROM items WHERE projectname=$projectsname";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure PHP for complete application projects is highly discouraged. It puts the coder in the position of worrying about elementary problems such as escaping queries, validating form data, security, templating, loading libraries, etc., etc. Instead of worrying about the program logic the coder puts too much time worrying about the syntax. Only newbies do that. We don't because time is money for us.

My recommendation: use framework. I personally recommend Codeigniter or Zend. Believe me it'll save you a lot of headache.

Comment: My experience with PHP frameworks is very limited, but I don't think they can eliminate the necessity of creating SQL queries. But I'll look into it.
While I appreciate your answer, I am a newbie, and I would still like to know the answer to my original question, because I think it will make me a better (and safer) PHP coder. I doubt there's a framework that can eliminate my need to know how my code works (or save me from my own ignorance); it would be great if there were.

Comment: Pardon me for that. I had no sleep for almost 48 hours so I was a bit grouchy :D It think your first question was already answered. About your 2nd question:  

The occurrence of the first double quote (") has more weight than the first single quote (') thereby parsing the variables inside the query. Thus, "Hi '$name'" is Hi Joe and 'Hi "$name"' is Hi "$name"